# PHP Filtering Form Input

Tags: php, forms, validation

Hello I have a simple form on my site that allows users to send feedback. The form is validated in more than one way sometimes I get emails that are just a bunch of gibberish like: sadfasdasd sadfsa dasd werqwer gsdfh hdfgh.

Question: Is there any clever way to check input string to prevent this?

Comment: Millions of duplicates. Search for them. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253527/email-address-validation-methods-subscribe-button, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161342/is-there-a-php-library-for-email-address-validation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email....

Comment: My entire question above is only one paragraph yet it seems you were incapable of reading and understanding it.

Comment: @EboMike He is not asking to validate email addresses, he is asking to detect spam in the message.

Comment: I fail at reading comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distinguishing between rubbish and sense is a very hard job for a computer and apparently not easy for humans either.  The only way to do that with any degree of success is to use some sort of spam filtering software.